# Iterating through a list and retrieving key-pair values [Scala/Play Framework]

Tags: scala, play-json

I have the following method:

```
  def myMethod = {
    val myJson: String = SOME_RESPONSE.\(SOME_FIELD).get.toString()
    val allValues: List[JsValue] = Json.parse(myJson).as[List[JsValue]]
    allValues.asInstanceOf[List[String]]
  }
```

It returns the following:

```
List({"key1":"value1","key2":"someField","key3":"asc"}, {"key1":"anotherValue","key2":"anotherField","key3":"desc"}, {"key1":"againAnotherValue","key2":"someField","key3":"asc"})
```

I know that I can extract the first element in the list with `myMethod.head`, however I would like to retrieve the value of `key1` or `key2` for all 3 elements in the list as I will need to use their value for some match operations.

Can you help?

**EDIT 1**

I decided to have `myMethod()` to return a L`ist[JsValue]`, in that way I can do the following:

```
myMethod.map(item => item \ KEY1_NODE).head.get
```

So, that will return the value for the head and I can of course do the same for the tail, but I was looking for a solution to iterate through all key1 keys. Any idea? I would need to return the actual value for the key and therefore it would not work if I use a foreach.

Comment: You should never ever use `.head` or `.get`

Answer (score 1):

Without case class, you can:

```scala
import play.api.libs.json._

val input = Json.parse("""[{"key1":"value1","key2":"someField","key3":"asc"}, {"key1":"anotherValue","key2":"anotherField","key3":"desc"}, {"key1":"againAnotherValue","key2":"someField","key3":"asc"}]""")

val reads = Reads[(String, String)] { js =>
  for {
    v1 <- (js \ "key1").validate[String]
    v2 <- (js \ "key2").validate[String]
  } yield v1 -> v2
}

input.validate(Reads.seq(reads))
// => JsSuccess(Vector((value1,someField), (anotherValue,anotherField), (againAnotherValue,someField)),)
```